# Link to the anchor moves to the wrong position because of changing page width

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, anchor

I can't solve one problem, but maybe someone will be able to find a solution?

On the left is content area (default width=70%). On the right is menu area (default width=30%).

When I scrolling page width of content becomes 100% and menu disappears:

```
.down .widget-area{
    width: 0;
}

.down .container{
    width: 100%;
}
```

It's good.

But at the beginning of the page there are links to few anchors:

```
<a href="#header1">GoTo Header 1</a>
<a href="#header2">GoTo Header 2</a>
<a href="#header3">GoTo Header 3</a>
```

When I click on a link "GoTo Header 1" everything is working properly.
But if I click on the link "GoTo Header 2" moves to the wrong position (under than the header title) because the script changes the width of the content area.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7uouhs6y

Please, any ideas?

Comment: `document.querySelector("#content").className = window.pageYOffset >= window.innerHeight ? "down" : "up";` - This crazy code behaving crazy. Your fiddle works without that: **http://jsfiddle.net/c9p1cs1m/**

Comment: Praveen Kumar, no, it does't work without script.
The script should expand the content area (green) to a width of 100% when I scroll down.

On the top of the page content area (red) is 70% and menu (green) is 30%. When I scroll down the content area should be expanded to width 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onscroll = function(){

    document.querySelector("#content").className = window.pageYOffset >= window.innerHeight ? "down" : "up";
}
```

According to your function above,when it's applying 100% width when you scroll down and offset is greater than innerHeight.To avoid that you should keep width to 70%.

Instead of this

```
.down .container{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Use this

```
.down .container{
    width: 70%;
}
```

Also don't specify height for left div,make it auto adjust according to content.

```
    .container{
        float: left;
        background: red;
      /*height: 300%;*/
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but then the content area (red) will not expand to 100% width, I need it.
On the top of the page content area (red) is 70% and menu (green) is 30%. When I scroll down the content area should be expanded to width 100%